# Netbeans debugger (used for Linux-C development) terminates(does not hit break points) during/after waitpid

Tags: c, netbeans, fork

We are working on client/server application. I'm working on logging of different sorts. We recently moved to netbeans IDE because of some administrative decision.

I was developer of Asp.net and recently moved to low-level programming. As I know only basics of C (course-level programmig), I spent 2 days in understanding forking concepts of C.

Now I'm debugging a piece of following code which is written by a very senior developer (ofcourse she is out of town):

```
int UpdateLogsDuringExecution(char *Input)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        //write data to file
        return 1; //on successful execution & 0 otherwise.
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED); //after this statement debugger does not hit any break points
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    }

    kill(0, SIGTERM); //if I change WUNTRACED to any other flag (for testing/understanding), debugger gives error something like Forward and Continue, Pause and Continue etc.
    return 1;
}

int main()

{
    setuid(0);
    int stat = 1;
    while (stat)
    {
        char *userInput = TakeUserInput();
        stat = UpdateLogsDuringExecution(userInput);
        if(!stat)
          break;
        stat= checkAndExecFlag();
        .
        .           
        .
        .
        //do more work

    }
    return 1;
}
```

**P.S this code works fine but I want to debug the code for understanding of business logic**

Please help me to understand this behavior. I think probably **waitpid** cause this behavior, if **WUNTRACED** was changed into any other flag, then **kill** cause the debugger to not hit any break points further.

All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

All function in my program have exactly same structure only

```
if(pid==0) //differs
```

Comment: I don't see any *business logic* here, only technical stuff ;) But anyways, if you just set a breakpoint at the `kill()` call, this should always be reached, given your child indeed terminates. Probably some misuse or misconfiguration of the debugger. Did you compile with all debugging symbols? Is the debugger configured to attach to child processes and might hang in some breakpoint *in the child*?

Comment: btw, removed inappropriate tag [tag:cthreads]. There's no threading here, especially not the one provided by the language in C11.

Comment: I understand that. We did not change anything in make file. Literally we just created a new project and moved code to that project. We are running/debugging with all default options of netbeans. Can you please give direction on how to do that? I mean I can see the option "Attach Debugger" in netbeans.

Comment: Thanks for removing @FelixPalmen

Comment: I can only play guessing game here ... when you have a `fork()` (or, on windows, `CreateProcess()`) in an active debugging sessions, the debugger has three options: Ignore the child process, attach to it and detach from the parent, or attach to both. That's normally configurable. If your debugger is attached to both processes and the child "hangs" because you have a breakpoint in there, you won't hit any breakpoints in the parent that's just waiting for the child with this code ...

Comment: Suppose if the program is running first time, if there is a break point in child process (say after `if(pid == 0)`, it will hit. whenever debugger reaches to 
    `waitpid or kill ()`
debugger just sleeps/terminates/ does not hit any further break points. Even in 2nd itreation debugger will not hit the same breakpoints. For that I think debugger is attached to both child and parent process. thanks for your effort and time :)

Comment: Dear @FelixPalmen I just realized that the above pasted code is creating alot of processes. Like 1(parent process) creates a process 2, 2 creates 3 and 3 creates 4... this goes on. Every time these functions are called they(parent) create processes and waits for process(child) to terminate. But when I exit (from exit command or by returning 0) then all processes terminate (I think). Can you please help me on this? killing a child process after return statement ? I can use exit but existing code depends upon status which is returned by almost all functions.

Comment: From the code above, there should never be more than 2 processes at a time. The function `fork()`s one and waits for it before returning, this should be safe. Something else must be wrong, in code not shown.

Comment: @FelixPalmen What happen when we do 
    return 1
 or 
    return 0 in child process ? does the child terminates after return ? I think probably not, because it keeps on running. I did
    exit(1)
 in child process but it exit from the program (terminates child and parent process). Sorry for bothering you. :)

Comment: `return` does always the same, so if you have `fork()` in a function other than main, it's probably not a good idea to `return` in the child process, use `exit()`. This **never** kills the parent. Your own code (`kill(0, SIGTERM)`) does, after waiting for the child. This sends `SIGTERM` to the whole process group which includes itself. See [man kill](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html)

Comment: @FelixPalmen thanks brother. You are a life saver. Just some findings, program execution never reaches to Kill(0....) until the function return 0 to main(). It results in creating alot of child processes. So thanks once again, I will use exit() and hopefully it will not end debugger.

Comment: one more thing please, should I use exit() or _exit() in child process to terminate itself?

Comment: I don't think `_exit()` is mentioned in the C standard, so don't use it unless there's a very good reason. And as for returning in the child code -- think about `fork()` as *cloning* the process (in fact, often a syscall named `clone` is used) -- this includes all the calling stack. You have twice the same process, so `return` will continue where the function was called (in the parent), like normal.